# C# How to edit Photo & Content place in button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I'm insert new button 
button have 2 Element Photo & Content 
how to set Photo in left and set Content in right

Image:

[image: Click Here To Show Image]

```
enter code here
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="New Journaly" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="434,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="21">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AccMH_V1000;component/Folder/Image/new.png" Stretch="None">
                <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-0.3"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button.Content` does not have to be `string`. Instead, you could also use a `StackPanel` or any other Container:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ...>
            <Image .../>
            <TextBlock .../>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
        <Button x:Name="button" Margin="0,0,0.4,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource btnStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="69">
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/AccMH_V1000;component/Folder/Image/new.png" Height="13" Margin="0,0,10,0"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Name="txt_firstblock" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White" >  New</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4DBo.jpg)